# How can I make a mapping to toggle cursorbind?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, options, cursor

I know that adding a `!` to the end of an option works for some commands, but it doesn't work for `cursorbind`. How can I toggle between `cursorbind` and `nocursorbind` with a keybinding?

Comment: How does it not work? `:set cursorbind!` toggles the option correctly for me. Note that to see an effect you have to set `cursorbind` in at least two windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function for it:

```
function! ToggleCursorbind()
  if &cursorbind == 1
    set nocursorbind
  else
    set cursorbind
  endif
endfunc
```

And then make a mapping using your function:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :call ToggleCursorbind()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:set cursorbind!
```

works. Now the issue is that this option is local to the window and needs to be done into several windows in order to see any result. Moreover, it binds line numbers and not cursor positions.

A mapping could be

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>whatever :<c-u>set cursorbind!<cr>:set cursorbind?<cr>
```